# Setting value in database as False dependent on a different value else True/False

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to set a value of an attribute in my MySQL DB using a ternary operator that is dependent on another variable/value that is available in the same model.

`item.rb` has a `belongs_to` relationship to `auction.rb`. An instance of an auction can be `online_only` or not. I am trying to set an attribute on an item instance called `manual_close` that is dependent on wether or not the auction is `online_only` or not.

so I have the following:

#### Item.rb:

```
def as_json(**options)
  json = {
    "manual_close" => self.manual_close?
  }
end

def manual_close?
  !online_only? false : self.manual_close
end

def online_only?
  auction && auction.online_only?
end
```

Say that `item.online_only? == false` then `item.manual_close` should `== false` if `item.online_only? == true` then `item.manual_close`can either be true or false.

#### Some `rails c` output:

[image]

a = Auction, i = Item. The json part is right but when I do `item.manual_close` it should be false instead of true.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code for `online_only?` method.

Comment: @Pavan added above

Comment: Your code doesn't trigger any changes in the DB to set the `manual_close` value to `true/false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are not updating your model in your database.

Defining a method called `manual_close?` will only override the method `manual_close?` (with the question mark) and will not affect the `manual_close` attribute in your database.

You will have to explicitly update `manual_close` in your database to get the results you are looking for.

```
i.update(manual_close: i.manual_close?)
```

I would recommend calling this line from an `after_save` callback on your `Auction` model. That way, every time the the auction model is updated, the item model will correctly reflect the state it needs to be.

Comment: Thank you I ended up doing something similar to this. I appreciate it.